# ArcGIS Experience Builder Filter Date Selector Label not correct

Tags: filter, arcgis-experience-builder, date-selector

The date/time selector within the Filter widget of ArcGIS Experience Builder in ArcGIS Online displays a label of month/year which doesn't seem to be configurable.

[image: example datetime image]

Is there a way to change the format of the label that displays when selecting a date/time value?  The expected format would be something like: 1/27/2023 11:58 AM.

Comment: Does the source layer have date data that contains the day?

Comment: Yes, they are full timestamps.